# SQL Server generating duplicate rows when transfering data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to use the AdventureWorks database to generate some test data for another database. When I execute the following query it produces 24 duplicate primary keys. So the query will not run unless I turn off the PK on the target db table.  The source db does not contain these duplicates.

```
INSERT INTO [TestDb] (TestId, Name, Location)
SELECT
  p.[BusinessEntityID],
  p.[FirstName]+ISNULL(p.[MiddleName], '')+p.[LastName],
  a.[City]
FROM [AdventureWorks2008R2].[Person].[Person] AS p
INNER JOIN [AdventureWorks2008R2].[Person].[BusinessEntityAddress] AS b
ON p.BusinessEntityID = b.BusinessEntityID
INNER JOIN [AdventureWorks2008R2].[Person].[Address] AS a
ON a.AddressID = b.AddressID;
```

Any suggestion as to why the duplicates are being created?
Is there a better way to generate test data?
What is the best way to delete duplicate rows, given that I don't care if I lose information?
Regards,
Dave

Answer (score 0):

May be try LEFT JOIN not sure about it though

Comment: this wont help at all if the problem is getting duplicates because the keys are not 1=1 relationship